# How to force my application to sleep?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an android application that uses the users Google Calendar to generate it's content dynamically. Randomly over the past month I've noticed that the app would have drained my battery in a couple of hours. This likely happens when the user's Google calendar has several hundred events (like mine does) and is a problem since I really don't need to be running in the background at all.

Obviously, I probably need to revise and rethink how I'm querying the for calendar events, but is there an easy way to force my app to stop once the user has navigated out of it?

Edit: my sourcecode is here: https://code.google.com/p/togenda/source/browse/ToGenda/src/edu/jcu/cs470/togenda/AgendaFragment.java

Comment: How do you query for calendar events?

Comment: Why not add some logic to the onStop method of your activity, which gets called when the app losses focus.

Comment: @FD_ right now I'm queering for events stored on the user's locally stored Google Calendar database (no internet permissions).

Comment: things you can do are use projection for query and limit the query frequency

Comment: @FD_ seeing as everything draws on screen correctly, I don't really understand why the application drains so much battery. If I had an infinite loop then my application should be stuck and never get to the point where it draws the content, but that is not the case.

because of this, I am looking for a way to just stop my application entirely and upload that to the android market until I've fixed the bigger issue.

Comment: try System.exit(1); universal solution

Comment: @IllegalArgument I really only need the initial query, when the fragment is loaded. I do not repeat the query, so that point might be unrelated.

Comment: @IllegalArgument Thank you. What I am trying to do atm is forcestop my app and upload that version to the market. (the version that drains battery is already up).
This will serve to stop my app from maliciously draining user's battery until I've pinpointed and fixed the actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!
It will serve as a temporary solution until I've figured out why my app drains battery in the first place.